# android emulator disconnecting from DDMS view when accessing file explorer

Tags: android, emulation, ddms

when i go to the DDMS view to access data folder of my app on an emulator, every thing works fine but after a few seconds the list of devices becomes empty which means that the DDMS lost connection with the emulator and even if i restart the adb server it keeps disconnecting and worst it doesnt even show the processes running on that emulator for the short perid of time when it is visible on the devices tab.

please could any one tell me if there is a solution.

thanks.

Comment: could you please tell me how to attach my logcat text file to this comment.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp

Comment: you can edit your own question and append your longcat text file

Answer (score 0):

You could use reset ADB menu in DDMS window as in attached.

[image]